# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable when I was changing instance attribute

Tags: python, object, instance, object-oriented-analysis

```py
class Airport:
    def __init__(self, code, city, country):
        self._code=code
        self._city=city
        self._country=country
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%s,%s)"%(self._code, self._city, self._country)
    def getCode(self):
        return self._code
    @property
    def getCity(self):
        print('property')
        return self._city
    @property
    def getCountry(self):
        return self._country
    @getCity.setter
    def setCity(self,city):
        print('changecity')
        self._city=city
    @getCountry.setter
    def setCountry(self,country):
        self._country=country

a1 = Airport("YXU", "London", "Canada")
a2 = Airport("ABC", "Madrid", "Spain")
a2.setCity("Athens")
a2.setCountry("Greece")
```

At `line 26 (a2.setCity("Athens"))`, I'm facing this error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Why is it wrong?
I didn't call any string as a function or use `str` as a variable name. Function `getCity` is alright, but `setCity` has something wrong. `a2` itself is an object, not a `str`.

Comment: You've created a property.  Unfortunately you've named it `getCity`, so you need to write `a.getCity = "Athens"`.  You probably want to name your property `city`.

Answer (score 4):

A `@setter` is called when you set the associated property.  Your properties are called `getCity` and `getCountry`, so instead of:

```
a2.setCity("Athens")
a2.setCountry("Greece")
```

do:

```
a2.getCity = "Athens"
a2.getCountry = "Greece"
```

If you want to call `getCity` and `setCity` as normal methods instead of treating `getCity` as a property whose setter is `setCity`, just remove the `@property` decorators.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I shouldn't have used that decorator.Thx